Itext Html to PDF Arabic text broken
When i am converting html to pdf in C# the arabic text is broken and also seems to be reversed.
I have tried direction rtl, adding arabic fonts.

.arabic {
      direction: rtl;
      unicode-bidi: isolate;
      font-family: 'NotoNaskhArabic', sans-serif;
  }

  @@font-face {
      font-family: 'NotoNaskhArabic';
      src: url('C:/Users/fahad.a/Downloads/NotoNaskhArabic-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
  }


 <td class="tdh" style="font-family: 'NotoNaskhArabic', sans-serif;">Date<span class="arabic" id="arabic" style="display:none; direction: rtl !important; font-family: 'NotoNaskhArabic', sans-serif;"><br>تاريخ الطلب</span></td>

ConverterProperties properties = new ConverterProperties();
FontProvider fontProvider = new FontProvider();
fontProvider.AddStandardPdfFonts();
fontProvider.AddFont("C:/Users/fahad.a/Downloads/NotoNaskhArabic-Regular.ttf"); // Ensure the path is correct
fontProvider.AddFont("C:/Users/fahad.a/Downloads/NotoKufiArabic-Regular.ttf"); // For bold text, if needed
properties.SetFontProvider(fontProvider);
properties.SetCharset("UTF-8"); // Ensure UTF-8 charset to handle Arabic script
// Add default styles
properties.SetCssApplierFactory(new DefaultCssApplierFactory());
iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfWriter writer = new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfWriter(destination, new WriterProperties().SetFullCompressionMode(true));
iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument pdfDocument = new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument(writer);
//iText.Kernel.Font.PdfFont f = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont("/fonts/NotoSansMyanmar-Regular.ttf", PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H, true);
HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf(htmltrimmed, pdfDocument, properties);
pdfDocument.Close();


you also need to install itext.pdfcalligraph that is listed on your screenshot (this add-on is not dual licensed, like itext core, or pdfhtml).

so i have to buy it?

itext.pdfcalligraph is already installed

@AndréLemos what should i do after buying the licensed of it)? can you please help me

with pdfCalligraph loaded, then things should work automagically. there's no special API that needs to get used. You can get a trial license to see if it works for you.

I got the license but its still can load pdfCalligraph, can you help?

what error are you getting?

there is no error, the pdf is generating but the arabic letters broken.
Images are shown above in gray (small Image)

@fahadshaikh I can see the same output as you, when I haven't added the pdfcalligraph to the current project.
<PackageReference Include="itext7.pdfcalligraph" Version="4.0.2" />
Please double check.

@Rainer can you please show the code?

when using the following iText code to convert from HTML to PDF I get the exepected result:
    LicenseKey.LoadLicenseFile(new FileInfo("licensefile.json"));
    using (FileStream htmlSource = File.Open("input.html", FileMode.Open))
    using (FileStream pdfDest = File.Open("output.pdf", FileMode.Create))
    {
      ConverterProperties properties = new ConverterProperties();
      FontProvider fontProvider = new FontProvider();
      fontProvider.AddStandardPdfFonts();
      fontProvider.AddFont("NotoNaskhArabic-Regular.ttf");
      properties.SetFontProvider(fontProvider);
      properties.SetCharset("UTF-8");
      HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf(htmlSource, pdfDest, properties);
    }

It is important that you also load the pdfCalligraph Add On and that it is included in your license. The C# project file should contain at least:
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="itext7" Version="8.0.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="itext7.bouncy-castle-adapter" Version="8.0.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="itext.licensing.base" Version="4.1.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="itext.licensing.remote" Version="4.1.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="itext7.pdfcalligraph" Version="4.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="itext7.pdfhtml" Version="5.0.4" />
  </ItemGroup>

For testing, I use the following sample HTML (input.html`)
<html>
<style>
    .rabic {
        direction: rtl;
        unicode-bidi: isolate;
        font-family: 'NotoNaskhArabic', sans-serif;
    }
  
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'NotoNaskhArabic';
        src: url('NotoNaskhArabic-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
    }
</style>
<body>
    <div style="font-family: 'NotoNaskhArabic', sans-serif;">Date<span class="arabic" id="arabic" style="direction: rtl !important; font-family: 'NotoNaskhArabic', sans-serif;"><br>تاريخ الطلب</span></div>
</body> 
  
</html>

And the result is:

hope this helps.
